# VPN disconnected: resolv.conf not refreshed

Tags: networking, vpn

I connect to VPN using vpnc.  When VPN disconnects, either via time out or the session limit is reached, VPN is terminated, but resolve.conf continues to contain references to my VPN network.

resolv.conf before VPN is connected:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search mylocalnetwork
```

resolv.conf after VPN is connected and remains once VPN is lost:

```
nameserver X.X.X.X
nameserver X.X.X.Z
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search internal.mycompany.com mylocalnetwork
```

In 10.04, when VPN lost, I'd run this script to refresh resolve.conf:

```
7$ cat bin/refreshResolvconf.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#if [ -e /etc/resolvconf/run/interface/tun0 -a "`pidof vpnc`" == "" ]; then /sbin/resolvconf -d tun0; fi
if [ -e /etc/resolvconf/run/interface/tun0 -a "`pidof vpnc`" == "" ]
then 
/sbin/resolvconf -d tun0;
echo "Refreshed resolv.conf"
fi
```

But, resolveconf changed in 12.04 changed, so this script is no longer applicable.

To resolve, I manually edit resolve.conf or turn off/on my connection via "gnome-control-center network".

Anyone else have the same problem?  How can resolv.conf be updated post-VPN disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

The path /etc/resolvconf/run is no longer used.

The following snippet will delete the tun0 record if no vpnc process is running.

```
[ "$(pidof vpnc)" ] || resolvconf -d tun0
```

The correct solution to the problem would be to arrange for vpnc to be terminated in such a way that it cleans up before exiting, where cleaning up includes deleting any resolvconf records it created when it connected.