# resolv.conf did not reset after VPN disconnection

Tags: networking, vpn, resolv.conf

My computer ran out of power while I was connected to a VPN, and when I turned my computer back on I was unable to access any websites. My resolv.conf file looks like:

```
# Generated by expressvpn
search expressvpn
nameserver X.X.X.X
```

with no mention of my local network, even though I am no longer connected to the VPN. I've tried reconnecting and then disconnecting from the VPN, but that didn't work. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I also tried the solution on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/146030/vpn-disconnected-resolv-conf-not-refreshed), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a terminal do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and reboot.

Comment: That's nice to hear!