# No wifi and bluetooth on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, bluetooth

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 from past 7-8 months. I was working on it and suddenly wifi disconnected and now I cannot see any option related to wifi. I guess bluetooth also dissapeared because both of them are wireless. I only installed Remmina from ubuntu software recently

after running wireless info script as suggested by this website, here's the link to it : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HG6x7KDjB4/

I have already tried `sudo service network-manager restart`.

`sudo lshw -class network` returns:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 0c
   serial: 74:e6:e2:28:47:31
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.046.00-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s29u1u1
   serial: 72:39:83:c6:bf:92
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.4 link=yes multicast=yes
```

I have also tried manual way as suggested in this website:https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

In the end after running autorun.sh, here's my output:

```
Check old driver and unload it.
rmmod r8168
Build the module and install
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
DEPMOD 4.15.0-47-generic
load module r8168
Updating initramfs. Please wait.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
Completed.
```

Comment: have you seen https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/ ? would require internet (utp) to do.

Comment: yes I have tried it. I didn't get which commands to run in the automatic way. so I executed commands as given in manual way. It didn't solve my problem

Comment: Have you been using ExpressVPN? I suddenly lost my network once using ExpressVPN and fixed it by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and reboot > source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/784994/resolv-conf-did-not-reset-after-vpn-disconnection

Comment: @Rinzwind check my updated question. there was a error Makefile:976

Comment: No I had recently installed Remmina from ubuntu store for remote desktop connection. I was working on it when it happened

Comment: You may want to take the laptop apart, remove and reinstall the wifi card.  It either has a bad connection to the motherboard or no longer functions